# check-in with photo in Facebook

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am wondering if there is any way to check-in with photo in Facebook. From document, facebook only provide coordinates, place, message and tags for parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the "picture" parameter when you post to USER_ID/checkins. The "picture" parameter holds the url to a picture e.g. "http://www.mywebsite.com/mypic.jpg". It only works with urls.

Comment: Nothing happens after I add "picture" with URL. Do I miss something?

Comment: Perhaps permissions are missing: user_checkins, publish_checkins, publish_stream...

Comment: All Permissions are set. I can post a check-in via Graph API Explorer but picture doesn't be included in check-in. The parameter I used, "picture = http://l.yimg.com/f/i/tw/hp/mh/09purple.gif" for picture.

Comment: the link goes to a '404 page not found' page on yahoo.

Comment: The hyperlink is generated by stackoverflow incorrectly. The correct hyperlink isn't included quotation marks. The correct one is  l.yimg.com/f/i/tw/hp/mh/09purple.gif .

Comment: Just figure out the location of picture. After check-in, it won't be shown in timeline but it is shown in the page of place mark. It doesn't work like facebook App.